# How to list the Hooks and order of execution in current loading page?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, customization, filters

I need to know the list of hooks that are called in the current page . How to identify the priority assigned to the action and filters in the action . If i want to remove the default action on word-press . It cause any error ?  May i overwrite the default action that to be execute?

```
add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

in this case i change the priority as 50 . i don't get any changes compare with 10 or Default. if This Priority value is for order of execution means i need to change the values as bigger or smaller?.

Comment: i asked this question before yours in stack overflow . How do you say its  duplicate (Feb 25-14) . Your post date (Sep 29 '14). @tazotodua

Comment: Ok goodview i accept it . No need to remove flag on this @tazotodua

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paste this into your functions.php

```
//LIST ALL HOOKS

function dump_hook( $tag, $hook ) {
    ksort($hook);

    echo "<pre>>>>>>\t$tag<br>";

    foreach( $hook as $priority => $functions ) {

    echo $priority;

    foreach( $functions as $function )
        if( $function['function'] != 'list_hook_details' ) {

        echo "\t";

        if( is_string( $function['function'] ) )
            echo $function['function'];

        elseif( is_string( $function['function'][0] ) )
             echo $function['function'][0] . ' -> ' . $function['function'][1];

        elseif( is_object( $function['function'][0] ) )
            echo "(object) " . get_class( $function['function'][0] ) . ' -> ' . $function['function'][1];

        else
            print_r($function);

        echo ' (' . $function['accepted_args'] . ') <br>';
        }
    }

    echo '</pre>';
}

function list_hooks( $filter = false ){
    global $wp_filter;

    $hooks = $wp_filter;
    ksort( $hooks );

    foreach( $hooks as $tag => $hook )
        if ( false === $filter || false !== strpos( $tag, $filter ) )
            dump_hook($tag, $hook);
}
```

Write this on index.php or single.php or any other page to see the filters applied to a particular function **along with priority**.

```
<?php  list_hooks(); ?>
```

This method even show your own create filters.

Comment: i cant paste it Sudeep . Because i want this info to my plugin .sorry

Comment: @RyanBabu : Sorry, I didn't realize that you want this for some plugin.

Comment: That's ok it may help some time thanks for your answer

Comment: @SudeepKRana, Quickly tested your code. Must say, it is blilliant.

Comment: Looks like the changes introduced with WP 4.7 break Sudeep's original code above.  The hooks passed to `ksort()` are WP_Hook objects now instead of arrays.  If I get a few minutes I'll post a fix.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: you need to include also  "elseif ($function['function'] instanceof Closure)
                            print_r($function);"   after the first if (not later) else you will not get all tags

Answer (score 2):

The lower priority numbers are executed first, higher numbers last

Comment: i changed the priority into 0 . but the default hook first called .     add_filter('authenticate', array($this, 'myfunction'), 0, 3);

Comment: @goose Gave you an up vote here but you could expand the answer. Isn't there code you can use to display hooks on the front end on page load rather than use a plugin which isn't compatible with the latest version of WordPress?